# Get Images Exposed by a RESTfull Service and use them in an HTML Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, bitmap

I'm currently exposing some application icons (such as the Notepad.exe icon) as bitmap data in JSON format through a RESTfull service. I'd like to capture the data using javasript and/or jQuery and display the original icons in my HTML website. The number of Icons exposed is not fixed but arbitrary. This means that,the website might have to dynamically create  tags to display the captured icons into(?). How can I do that? Would it be easier to achieve my goal if I was to expose the icons as Base64 strings in JSON/XML format? Any other ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that your service response points to a image url instead of adding the image data to the response. then on response, you can iterate your object and add as many img tags as you want and set their source to whatever the service gives you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I solved this by having my service returning an array of base64 strings where each string holds the binary data of the corresponding image. The base64-encoded strings are then captured in my HTML document and decoded using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: you know you can add the base64 binary encoded data directly as a src of an image ? there's no need to decode it. it just needs the correct mime/type header for example on png's `data:image/png;base64,.......`

Comment: Yes I know and that's exactly what I m doing in my code. I referred to it as "decoding" because that's what I believe it's happening when you do so. Thank a lot anw! You've been really helpful to me!! - @TheBrain